# Best way to store a textfile (approx 6-30 kB) in a variable

Tags: .net, vb.net

I would like to store a plain text logfile (approx 6 - 30 kB) in a variable belonging to a class that I later serialize. One way to do it is obviously reading it in and storing it to a string. Is there a better way?

Comment: It will be okay with this size but as the size grows if might become bigger than String size allowed since variable sizes in VB are fixed.Use of Variant datatype as opposed to String will give to more memory .Better approach if possible would be to serialize in parallel to reading if possible.

Answer (score 1):

Is this an output text file? Rather than a string, which is immutable, you could use a [System.Text.StringBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Better is subjective.  If you are not hitting any measured performance problems, and there are no requirements preventing it, just store it as a string.

Answer (score 1):

Strings in .NET are Unicode, meaning that each character will use two bytes. If you know you can store your log file in a 1 byte per character encoding, you could save space by storing it as a byte array. However 30KB are not much so I wouldn't be too concerned about it unless you had thousands of these.